# Why does iPhone Safari not save login credentials for a certain Wi-Fi hotspot?

Tags: iphone, safari

My Academy's wi-fi requires me to log in via a web-browser portal page before I have access to the internet. Safari on my iPhone doesn't save my username and password for it. Is there a way to manually force it to save them?

Answer (score 1):

check out this link http://www.ausbt.com.au/how-to-save-passwords-in-safari-on-the-ipad-iphone to setup autofill name and passwords for safari on IOS.

And it totally is a matter of safari not remembering username/password.

It's a little hidden, but it's there, and thanks for asking a good question. The other answerers here must never have logged into a captive portal before or something.

Comment: This does not work as on the page I am using the user is never prompted to 'save password' so nothing is stored

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to log in using Safari?

Otherwise you go to 'System Preferences' > 'Wi-Fi' > Select the appropriate network > Log in > Deselect 'Ask To Join Networks'
This way, your iPhone remembers this Wi-Fi network and your iPhone will automatically connect to this network when you're within the range of the academy Wi-Fi.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The academy requires him to log in via a log-in page on the web browser like most other public hotspots.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a "captive portal" - a wifi network where you need to input your password into a form on a web page, or check a box agreeing to terms of use, then in my experience the iPhone will not remember the password.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a matter of Safari not remembering the password, its a matter of the network requiring login based on the browser.  Most captive walled gardens require it with every disconnect for security purposes.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem. Turns out I was in Private Browsing mode.